# Nodejs app loops continuously and doesnot load the page, as well as cant send post request using postman

Tags: node.js

> I am trying to create an api and send post request using the postman,
>   but for some reason I'm not getting the data which is sent through the
>   post man. Instead when I cancel the postman send request I get
>   response which is shown in the screenshot.

Postman Screenshot: 
[image: Postman, post request screenshot]

nodejs server response screenshot: 
[image: Response I'm getting after I cancel the Postman send request]

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');  
const cors = require('cors'); 

// importing custom created modules
const config = require('./config');

// Instantiating express
const app = express();

// Connecting to the mongodbLab
mongoose.connect(config.database, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (error) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log('Error :',error);
    } else {
        console.log('Connected to the database.');
    }
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); 
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(cors);

const userRoutes = require('./routes/account');
app.use('/api/accounts', userRoutes);

// Running the server at port 3000
app.listen(config.port, error => {
    console.log('Server started with config file at Port: ' + config.port);
});
```

account.js

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'); // Encrypts user data.

router.post('/signup', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body);
});

module.exports = router;
```

> I tried even changing from https://localhost:3000 to
>   http://localhost:3000 as suggested in this post   [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52677872/localhost-sent-an-invalid-response-for-my-angular-app)
>
> And even tried adding res.end() as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805438/node-js-server-just-keeps-loading-with-no-result) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55389088/localhost-didnt-send-any-data-err-empty-response).
>   But nothing is working, If I goto localhost:3000 the server just keeps loading infinitely. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I got the solution, it was because of `app.use(cors)`. I don't know why but when I commented out this line everything started to work perfectly.
But in the response although I get the json object. But there is an array of Object, which I didn't get.

Here's the response screenshot: 
[image]

**Edit:**
I finally got it I didn't call the cors() method properly. It should have been `app.use(cors())`, but I called it as just `app.use(cors)` missing paranthesis().
Now Everything is working fine.

Comment: `cors` should not be a actual cause in your code as you are not making a request from other domain. Your code possibly was breaking due to other logical mistakes.

Comment: Maybe, but when I followed the above method it did work.

Comment: You were right passing just `cors` to app.use will cause this problem